# Python Kivy. The label does not have a text, however, i assigned it's value to the variable

Tags: python, kivy

There are some buttons on the second screen. If one of them is pressed - the screen changes and on the other screen there is a label that should have the text that was on the pressed button. No error is shown, while the label does not have any text at all.

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        btn = Button(text = "word is here", on_release =self.pressedFunction)
        self.ids.container.add_widget(btn)

        btn1 = Button(text = "another word is here", on_release    =self.pressedFunction)
        self.ids.container.add_widget(btn1)

    def pressedFunction(self, instance, *args):
        self.manager.current= "three"

        screenThree = ScreenThree()
        text = str(instance.text)

        screenThree.changing_label(text)

class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def changing_label(self, text):
        self.ids.my_label.text = text

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("example.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
   MainApp().run()
```

Kivy:

```
ScreenManagement:
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:
    ScreenThree:

<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "press me"
            on_release: app.root.current = "two"

<ScreenTwo>:    
    name: "two"

    BoxLayout:
        id: container


<ScreenThree>:
    name: "three"

    BoxLayout:
        id: labelContainer

        Label:
            text: ""
            id: my_label
```

I have also tried puttin print here:

```
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def changing_label(self, text):
        self.ids.my_label.text = text
        print(self.ids.my_label.text)
```

And it shows the correct value that I expect, but then there is still nothing on the label.

Comment: This is a common problem that people have with kivy/python. Your `.kv` file creates a `ScreenManager` with three child `Screens`. These are all created when your '.kv` file is loaded. In your `pressedFunction()` method, you are creating another `ScreenThree` instance in `screenThree = ScreenThree()`. So when you call `screenThree.changing_label(text)` you are calling a method on a `Screen` that is not part of your display. You need to call the method of the already existing `ScreenThree` that is a child of your `ScreenManager`.

Comment: By the way, `Screen` objects are required to have `name` properties. Your `ScreenOne` is missing a `name`.

Comment: You can replace the `screenThree = ScreenThree()` with `screenThree = self.manager.get_screen('three')`.

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

### 1. Switching Screen before populating my_label.text

Populating of `my_label.text` was done after screen is switched, `self.manager.current = "three"`.

### 2. ScreenThree - Blank/Black Window

***ScreenThree*** instantiated twice. The first instance is created in kv file by `ScreenThree:` (this is equivalent to `ScreenThree()` in Python Code). The second instance is created in Python code, `screenThree = ScreenThree()`.

The populating of the `my_label.text` is in the second instance/object and not in the first instance. Therefore, the ScreenThree is blank/black window because app is using the view as per kv file i.e. the first instance of ScreenThree.

#### Note:

If you add `id()` function, it will shows different memory locations for the screens.

```
def pressedFunction(self, instance, *args):
    self.manager.current = "three"

    self.debug()

    screenThree = ScreenThree()

    print("screenThree={0}, id(screenThree)={1}".format(screenThree, id(screenThree)))

    self.debug()

    text = str(instance.text)
    screenThree.changing_label(text)

def debug(self):
    print("\ndebug:")
    print("\tself.manager.screen_names=", self.manager.screen_names)
    print("\tself.manager.screens=", self.manager.screens)
    for x in self.manager.screens:
        print("\t\tscreen={0}, id(screen)={1}".format(x, id(x)))
```

## Solution

### kv file

1. Add `id: screen_two` under `ScreenTwo:`. This will be used to reference class attributes / methods in ScreenTwo.
2. Replace `app.root.current = "two"` with `root.manager.current = "two"` because every screen has by default a property `manager`

### Python code

1. Add import statement, `from kivy.properties import StringProperty`
2. Declare StringProperty inside class ScreenTwo(), `text = StringProperty('')` so there is no need to pass parameters around and also encapsulation.
3. In pressedFunction() method, replace `text = str(instance.text)` with `self.text = str(instance.text)`
4. Populate text before switching screen
5. In class ScreenThree(), rename `changing_label()` method to `on_pre_enter()` method, and remove `text` from the argument list.
6. Replace `self.ids.my_label.text = text' with`self.ids.my_label.text = self.manager.ids.screen_two.text`
7. ***Optional:*** Reduce memory used, replace `return presentation` with `return Builder.load_file("example.kv")` and remove `presentation = Builder.load_file("example.kv")`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    text = StringProperty('')

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        print("\nScreenTwo.on_pre_enter:")

        btn = Button(text = "word is here", on_release =self.pressedFunction)
        self.ids.container.add_widget(btn)

        btn1 = Button(text = "another word is here", on_release =self.pressedFunction)
        self.ids.container.add_widget(btn1)

    def pressedFunction(self, instance, *args):
        self.text = str(instance.text)      # populate before switching screen
        self.manager.current = "three"  # switch screen


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.my_label.text = self.manager.ids.screen_two.text


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("example.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

### example.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

ScreenManagement:
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
    ScreenThree:

<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "press me"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "two"    # every screen has a default property manager

<ScreenTwo>:
    name: "two"

    BoxLayout:
        id: container


<ScreenThree>:
    name: "three"

    BoxLayout:
        id: labelContainer

        Label:
            id: my_label
            text: ""
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - ScreenTwo]
[image: Img02 - ScreenThree Button1's Text displayed]
[image: Img03 - ScreenThree Button2's Text displayed]